# Reset select values in v-autocomplete, in order to add multiple items

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm creating an application that has a selection box to choose between some template data. However, the user should be able to select the same template option several times and, each time he selects the template, a new informational box appears in the screen.

My problem is that the v-autocomplete component doesn't enable this kind of behavior: we can select one option (or multiple options), but not the same option twice.

I thought about making something like this: every time the user selects the option A, the infobox would appear below and the component would reset to a empty option. Then, the user could choose option A again and, when he chooses it, another info box would appear, how many times the user needs it.

How could I do something like this using vue? I didn't found any component that would do something like this on default, so I think I'll have to tweak the component behavior, but I don't know exactly where to start.

My template:

```js
<template>
  <div class="select-wrapper" id="selectBox">
    <v-autocomplete
      class="select-input"
      :items="items"
      :name="label"
      placeholder="select item"
      solo
      :value="value"
      @change="$event => onChange($event, items)"
      item-text="name"
      item-value="value"
      :required="required"
      :rules="[
        value =>
          !required ||
          !!value ||
          "required"
      ]"
    ></v-autocomplete>
  </div>
</template>
```

And my Vue code:

```js
<script lang="ts">

import { defineComponent } from "@vue/composition-api";
import Vue from "vue";

interface SelectItem {
    name: string,
    value: string
}

interface SelectBoxProps {
  items: SelectItem[];
  value: string;
  onSelect: ({ target }: { target?: SelectItem }) => void;
  hasResetSelection: boolean;
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: "SelectBox",
  props: {
    label: String,
    items: Array,
    value: [String, Number],
    onSelect: Function,
    disabled: Boolean,
    required: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    },
    hasError: Boolean,
    errorMessage: String,
    hasResetSelection: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false
    }
  },
  directives: {
    ClickOutside
  },
  setup({ onSelect, hasResetSelection }: SelectBoxProps) {
    const onChange = (selectedValue: string, itemsArr: SelectItem[]) => {
      const targetItem = itemsArr.find(i => i.value === selectedValue);

      if (hasResetSelection) {
        Vue.nextTick(() => {
          console.log("onselect should reset value");
          return onSelect({ target: { name: "", value: "" } });
        });
      }
      return onSelect({ target: targetItem });
    };

    return {
      onChange
    };
  }
});
</script>
```

This was my last attempt with **Vue.nextTick**, I already tried to tweak the component with **ref()** and it didn't work as well. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another variable just to hold the input for the `autocomplete` component Like this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    items: [{ name : 'hello', value : 1 }, { name : 'world', value : 2 }],
    value : null,
    values : []
  },
  methods: {
    onChange() {
      this.values.push(this.value)
      this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.value = null
      })
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      Values : {{values}}
      <v-autocomplete
        :items="items"
        placeholder="select item"
        solo
        v-model="value"
        item-text="name"
        item-value="value"
        @change="onChange"
      />
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```